# How to sort an array $A[1..n]$ where all but $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ elements are integers in range $\sqrt n$ to $n\sqrt n$, at $\Theta(n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

Without the unknown $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ elements this question wouldn't be hard.

After a long time trying to solve the question, the best partial idea I have is to use *Radix sort* for the $n-\sqrt n$ elements which are in the given range.  Then I would need to sort the $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$ elements in a decent time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how raidx sort lets you get away with O(n) sorting on that range but assuming thats the case you could try proving that sqrt(n)*log(sqrt(n)) is in O(n)

Comment: Are the elements non-negative integers?

Comment: @Steven Just some of them (the ones in the known range).

Comment: @Jake I forgot to add they are integers.

Comment: @Jake You are right about sqrt(n) thing. And, for the radix sort part see this:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-n-numbers-range-0-n2-1-linear-time/

Comment: This I guess completes the answer.

Comment: `I forgot to add they are integers.` Then please edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

In the rest of the answer I will slightly abuse the notation by treating $A$ as a set. For simplicity I will also assume that the integers to sort are distinct, so that we are dealing with sets instead of multisets. This assumption is easy to remove.

Construct a min-heap $H^-$ and a max-heap $H^+$, each containing all elements in $A$. Extract the minimum  $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ times from $H^-$ and let $S^-$ be the set of the extracted elements.
Similarly, extract the maximum $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ times from $H^+$, and let $S^+$ be the set of the extracted elements. The overall time required so far is $O(n) + O(\sqrt{n} \log n) = O(n)$. (Notice also that $S^- \cap S^+ = \emptyset$ since $2 \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor \le n$ for $n > 1$).

Now you know that all the elements in $A \setminus (S^- \cup S^+)$ are integers between $0$ and $n^{3/2}$ (actually, between $\sqrt{n}$ and $n^{3/2}$, but this is irrelevant), and therefore can be sorted in time $O(n)$ using Radix sort (indeed, each integer in $S \setminus (S^- \cup S^+)$ has just two digits when written in base $n$).
Let $A'$ be the sorted version of $A \setminus (S^- \cup S^+)$.

To obtain a sorted version of $A$, we just need to insert the elements in $S^- \cup S^+$ into the right position of $A'$.
This can be done by first sorting $S^- \cup S^+$ in time $O(n)$ (any quadratic-time algorithm suffices since $|S^- \cup S^+| \le 2 \sqrt{n}$) and then merging the resulting sorted sequence with $A'$ a-la-Mergesort.